# Is studying Alternate Coordinate System required game development?

Tags: mathematics, linear-algebra

I don't know whether or not this question is fit for Gamedev.Stackexchange, but I would like to know :-

I am new to Linear Algebra. I only want to study those parts of Linear Algebra which would be required for making games. **Alternate Coordinate System**, is it required for making games, or should I just study Vector Spaces and Matrix Transformations?

Comment: Depends on the type of game really. Making Tetris? Not important.

Comment: Knowing how to translate between different co-ordinate systems is important for most kinds of games. But like Almo says... if I were you, I'd just deal with it when I come to it. It's always better to learn things in the context where you expect to use it, rather than from some abstract non-game-related source.

Comment: IF you have a specific game in mind, THEN aim for the game and learn what you need as you go, ELSE learn whatever's handy, it's all good brain exercise and you have pretty much unlimited storage so enjoy all the knowledge and thinking, and math is fun.

Comment: In most games, vectors and matrices are all you need. If you've done that, you can do pretty much any thing. If there is a case where you need to use another coordinate system, then look it up, otherwise don't.